# Geotools WFS basic authentication

Tags: wfs, geotools, authentication

I'm trying to retrieve data from remote WFS server which requires basic `https` authentication using GeoTools.
I  defined connection parameters for username and password like

```
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:USERNAME", "username" );
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:PASSWORD", "pass" );
```

However I get

```
"Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://...".
```

What is the solution for basic `https` authentication in GeoTools WFS support.

Comment: try turning logging up and see if that shows you what is sent

Comment: Can you show how you're applying the `connectionParameters`?

Comment: For connectionParameters: 

Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();

Comment: I get:
IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://wfsserver/wfs (unfortunately I had to change wfs server name)
and 
IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://wfsserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=COM:CITIES (unfortunately I had to change wfs server name)

Comment: I have the same case that you report. I have a connection with basicAuthentication, the getCapabilities and getFeatureStore return me correct data but when i try to commit a transaction I get the next exception: "HTTP response code:401 for url ...." Here's my code: public boolean anadirIncidencia(String getCapabilities, String capa, SimpleFeature incidencia, String username, String password) throws Exception { boolean b = false; Map connectionParameters = new HashMap(); connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities); connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStore

Answer (score 2):

I can recreate this response from a local GeoServer but only when I send a connection request to a GeoServer that doesn't have a user of the name requested. When I have set up a user then it works exactly as I expect.

With regards to @Dani's comment I don't get a `FeatureStore` which is expected as the WFSStore doesn't support writes when you use version 1.1.0. For version 1.0 it works as expected when the user exists on the server.